# How to speed up multiple counts query and get a result

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query I'm trying to write to get counts of active users and active contacts associated with each account. I have attempted to run the counts separately and in both cases they run at under 1 sec but when I put them together as seen below I don't get a result. Please let me know if there is anything I can do it enhance the query.

```
select  count(c.c_no) as contacts_count, count(u_no) as user_count, a.* 
from accounts a
LEFT JOIN users u on u.a_no = a.a_no and u_status = 1
LEFT JOIN IDP1.contacts c on c.a_no = a.a_no and c_status = 1
where a_status = 1
group by a_no
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use * and aggregate functions simultaneously

Try this

```
select  count(c.c_no) as contacts_count, count(u_no) as user_count, a_no
from accounts a
LEFT JOIN users u on u.a_no = a.a_no and u_status = 1
LEFT JOIN IDP1.contacts c on c.a_no = a.a_no and c_status = 1
where a_status = 1
group by a_no
```